# angular beforeEach inject causing simple test to fail

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine

Whenever I try to inject an angular service, my simple Jasmine test fails. However, if I remove the inject, it works. The following causes an error to be thrown:

```js
describe('rule.js file', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    console.log('What the heck is wrong???: ' + $controller);
  }));
  it('foo should be equal to 1', function() {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

This is the error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) rule.js file foo should be equal to 1 FAILED

However, if I comment out the inject line like so:

```js
describe('rule.js file', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  it('foo should be equal to 1', function() {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

The test passes.

Anyone have any clue on what could be wrong?

Edit: Here are my karma.conf included files

```
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js',
  'bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js',
  'bower_components/angular-deferred-bootstrap/angular-deferred-bootstrap.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router.stateHelper/statehelper.js',
  'bower_components/lz-string/libs/lz-string.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-scroll/dist/ui-scroll.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-scrollpoint/dist/scrollpoint.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-event/dist/event.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-indeterminate/dist/indeterminate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-uploader/dist/uploader.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-utils/index.js',
  'bower_components/angular-recaptcha/release/angular-recaptcha.js',
  'bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bowser/src/angular-bowser.js',
  'bower_components/ngAnimate-animate.css/animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-truncate/src/truncate.js',
  'bower_components/blob-polyfill/Blob.js',
  'bower_components/file-saver.js/FileSaver.js',
  'bower_components/angular-file-saver/dist/angular-file-saver.bundle.js',
  'bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.js',
  'bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  "app/scripts/viewlevels.js",
  "app/scripts/global.js",
  "app/scripts/hrbui.js",
  "app/scripts/hrb-mask.js",
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'unit-tests/global.js',
  'unit-tests/specs/**/*.js',
```

Comment: can you paste your karma.conf included files

Comment: @Don I have added my karma.conf files in my original post.

Comment: can you check if angular-mocks an angular are of same version

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - but yes, they are both v1.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it passes is because you really aren't testing anything.  There is a bit more that you need to do with the controller before the test can actually run.  I think if you structure things like below, it should work:

```js
describe('rule.js file', function() {
  var controller;
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    controller = _$controller_('yourControllerName', {$scope: $scope});
    
    console.log('What the heck is wrong???: ' + controller);
  }));
  it('foo should be equal to 1', function() {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I am a bit late to the answer it seems, but hopefully this can help someone.